# Converting fraction from any base to decimal - unable to use negative powers with BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am in the process of building a number base converter application.

I am stuck on how to convert the fractional portion to decimal before converting to the target base.

For example:

User elects `from base 16` `to base 20`.

Number in `base 16` = `ab.375`

The calculation I am trying to code for this particular example is:

```
Base 16 to decimal calculation:

(ab.375)16 = (10 × 16 ^ 1) + (11 × 16 ^ 0) + (3 × 16 ^ -1) + (7 × 16 ^ -2) + (5 × 16 ^ -3) = (171.216064453125)10
```

I have a separate method that outputs correctly for the portion of user input prior to the decimal point. My problem is how to account for fractional portion and the `negative powers` since `BigDecimal` `pow` method cannot be `< 0`

Here is my `convertToDecimalFraction` method:

```
    public static String convertToDecimalFraction(int sourceBase, String fraction) {

        String[] fractionToConvertArray = ArrayUtilNoFraction.numberToArray(fraction);

        int basePowers = -1;

        BigDecimal integerToDecimalBig = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        for (String s : fractionToConvertArray) {
            integerToDecimalBig = integerToDecimalBig
                    .add(BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(s))
                            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(sourceBase).pow(basePowers)));
            basePowers = basePowers - 1;
        }
        return integerToDecimalBig.toString();
    }
```

In case you're curious, here is my `ArrayUtilFraction.numberToArray`:

```
    public static String[] numberToArray(String numberToConvert) {

        String[] numberToConvertArray = String.valueOf(numberToConvert).split("");

        String[] possibleValues = new String[]{
                "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
                "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
                "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
        };

        StringBuilder outputValues = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;

        for (String number : numberToConvertArray) {
            for (String value : possibleValues) {
                if (number.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                    outputValues.append(count).append(" ");
                    break;
                } else {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        return outputValues.toString().split(" ");
    }
```

Comment: x^-n = 1/(x^n) hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips.

- It isn't necessary to continuously use the `pow` function.  Consider a base `16` value of `1EF.2DA`.
- The power will be `3` since you have three digits to the left of the `radixPoint`.  Since the radix will be `16` so set your initial divisor to

```
      divisor = BigDecimal.pow(16,3);
```

- Then, remove the decimal point from the string, giving `1EF2DA`.
- Now, using a starting value of `b = BigDecimal.ZERO`  loop thru the digits from left to right.  `charToBase10` is a map to go from source radix to base10 (e.g. `E to 14`)

```
       b = b.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(charToBase10.get(digit))
                    .multiply(divisor));
       divisor = divisor.divide(sourceRadix);
```

- Each time thru the loop, `b` is being built to contain the number.  Since the divisor will eventually be less than `1` the fractional portion will gradually appear.

And here is a quick trick to convert any decimal fractional value to another base.

- assume you wanted to convert .45(10) to base `2`. Output would be appended to bits.

```
2*.45 = 0.90 non-fraction portion is 0 so first bit is 0
2*.90 = 1.80 non-fraction portion is 1 so next bit is  1
2*.80 = 1.60 - next bit is 1
2*.60 = 1.20 - next bit is 1
2*.20 = 0.40 - next bit is 0
2*.40 = 0.80 - next bit is 0
2*.80 = 1.60 - next bit is 1  (and we have reached a repeating point)
So the answer is

bits = .0111001[10011001100110011....]
```

This will work for any base and you will need to have a map to map the proper characters.  You'll also have to determine how much precision in the entire process you want to preserve.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am relatively very new to Java, so I look forward to sharing my completed application for SO code review shortly. I am choosing to code my own methods instead of using built in methods like `charToBase10` so I can learn as much as possible. Not about optimization yet, more or less about understanding the basics!

Comment: You're most welcome!  Just so you're aware, `charToBase10` is not a built in method.  It is an instance of a class in the API called `HashMap.`  In that regard it is no different than using `String` or `BigDecimal` which are also classes in the API.